# How to set a default value from the model in a DropDownListFor?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor, enums

I'm using `DropDownListFor` to create a drop-down of enums. I am creating an edit profile page that lets the user edit there level, so I want by default to have what they had in their profile selected, just in case they don't want to change that field. So if they had sophomore in their profile the drop-down should default to sophomore selected. How do I set the default value to be what was from the model(or the database)?

I have tried adding an option label like so, but it adds an extra select item, that I don't need. I just need what they already have in the model to be selected.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AcademicInfo.ClassLevel, Html.GetEnumSelectList<ClassLevel>(), Model.ClassLevel.ToString())
```

Model:

```
public class ViewModel
{
 [Display(Name = "Class Level")]
 public ClassLevel ClassLevel { get; set; }
}
```

HTML in View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AcademicInfo.ClassLevel, Html.GetEnumSelectList<ClassLevel>())
```

Enum:

```
public enum ClassLevel
{
    Freshman = 1,
    Sophomore = 2,
    Junior = 3,
    Senior = 4
    //Other = 5
}
```

How I add it to the model:

```
ViewModel model = new  ViewModel();
model.ClassLevel = (ClassLevel)latestYear.ClassLevelId;
```

I need to be able to set a default value from the model

Comment: Perhaps you should post the *actual* code instead of trying to recreate an approximation. I'm fairly sure that class isn't actually "ViewModel" and has more than this one property for example. Also, in your view you're binding to `Model.AcademicInfo.ClassLevel` which is not represented here at all. The issue is very likely down to pieces you aren't including

Comment: Sorry, I didn't post all the code, I couldn't do all of it. but it turns out I was binding to the wrong model, seem like such a minor thing but was confusing to find. Thanks @ChrisPratt, that fixed it.

Comment: `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ClassLevel, Html.GetEnumSelectList<ClassLevel>())` is what I changed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens naturally when you map the data onto your view model. In other words, if the entity has `ClassLevel` set to `ClassLevel.Sophmore`, then you would map that value onto the `ClassLevel` property on your view model, which will then *also* be `ClassLevel.Sophmore`. Then, since you've bound the select to the `ClassLevel` property, the value of the dropdown will automatically be set to the value of the property, i.e. `ClassLevel.Sophmore` in this case.

Comment: I believe I do binding to the view model here, but it does not seem to work. `model.ClassLevel = (ClassLevel)latestYear.ClassLevelId;`

Comment: I added how I do the binding in the question.